# Find out why Windows Azure returns a 301

Tags: facebook, azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm setting up a callback web page hosted in Azure app services (asp.net / IIS), to receive callbacks from Facebook. Using a test tool on Facebook, I keep receiving HTTP code 301. In the Azure IIS logs I can indeed see the request coming in (to the correct URL, using https) and a 301 being returned. A previous call to the same page but using GET (also from Facebook, as part of their verification of the page) works just fine, and a simple POST from my own test app works as well.

It's not set up for redirection in my site, so it seems to be something on a higher level.

My questions: is there any way to see why Azure decides to return a 301, and which URL it is redirecting to which other URL? And seeing as from my own test app it works just fine, can redirection like this be set up based on content type or something like that?

Comment: i suggest you can try to use Remote debugging to check whether the redirect request access into your redirection page. Please follow this document to set up your remote debugging env.
(https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introduction-to-remote-debugging-on-azure-web-sites/).Meanwhile, I wonder know what's rule of URL Rewrite in your web.config file.